# Display Images in right position with middle align

Tags: html

```
img {
vertical-align: middle;
}

.right
{
???
}

<img align='right' class='right' src='images/online_icon.png' border="0" width=8/>
```

What I want to do is :
display images in right position with middle align.

I already test images align middle, but when I try to give the position in right, it change the position a slight upward.

Any suggestions ?

I have an solution for my case. That's :
add padding in class .right below:

```
.right
{
    float: right;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Add the solution as an answer and accept it, it then follows the Q&A principle of this answer, and helps users to check the accepted answer right away :)

Comment: you can answer you're own questions.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image in a div and align the div to right.

```
<div align="right">
   <img src='images/online_icon.png' border="0" width=8/>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you !!
Yeshwanth

Comment: hi... I want to set the display of images in right position and then middle align

Comment: Dear, using vertical-align depends on the HTML element for which you are trying to apply. Vertical-align is not working just because it isn't exactly the same that most of us understand. Please let us know if you are following div based or table based design. And before that please refer to http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html